# please exclaim me a calculation that I have faced in Python if you have time

Tags: python

```
x=[3,7,5,9]
y=[2,4,8,7]
z=x[1] + y[2]
print(z)
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? What is it you don't understand?

Comment: That would print 15. What is the actual question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two lists:

```py
x = [3, 7, 5, 9]
y = [2, 4, 8, 7]
```

The lines

```py
z = x[1] + y[2]
print(z)
```

assigns the result of adding the element in `x` with index 1 (**remember, indices start at 0**) and the element in `y` with index 2. That is

```py
z = 7 + 8
```

and then we print the result of that

```py
15
```

Comment: While this is a well-explained and good answer, there is not a question to answer for in the first place... Please according to site policy try to avoid answering badly-asked questions as it encourages people to ask those.

Comment: @Tomerikoo You're right, I definitely see the problem, and I'm sorry. I usually flag questions like these, but for some reason it seemed like a somewhat well-phrased question, and I answered it. I now realise that the question is not at all good, and I will refrain from quickly answering such questions in the future. Thanks for reminding me!